# Do we need to put an article after "by"?

Tags: prepositions, articles, definite-article

I've encountered many phrases like the following:

> It was performed by band the Beatles
> It was made by machine
> ...which was built by architect [name]

So, I guess when we want to state that something came into existence (or something was done to it) by someone, we omit the definite article before that *someone*, is that right?

Could you please give the exact rule on this topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whether *the* is required in your examples depends on the context:

> > It was made by machine

is a way of saying that it was made mechanically and not by hand.

> > It was made by a machine

means that it was made by a machine that has not been identified.

> > It was made by the machine

means that it was made by a machine that you have already identified.

You cannot say: *It was designed/built by architect* without an *article*.
Either: *It was designed by an architect* (who has not been identified)
Or: *It was designed by the architect* (whom you have already referred to)

Thus you could write either: *It was designed by John Smith, (who is) an architect*, or: *It was designed by John Smith, the architect* (which assumes that John Smith is well known as an architect.

The same rule applies to *band*. Music is not performed *by band*, but either by *a band* (unidentified) or *the band* (already identified).

Comment: You might find the phrase "by band The Beatles" in a headline, a title, or a picture caption: these have a special grammar which allows some articles to be omitted. But not in normal prose.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation for sentences 1 and 3. You seem to be saying that they are not correct. The OP asks about "it was built by architect John Smith", not "it was built by architect". "It was built by architect John Smith" sounds fine in my ears.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck There are certain professions in which the position becomes part of the honorific. Thus we talk of President John Smith or Doctor John Smith. But we don't talk of Architect John Smith, Lawyer John Smith or Surgeon John Smith. In these instances we conventionally speak of *the* architect/lawyer/surgeon, John Smith. You don't have to but it's the norm.

Comment: I agree that *the architect* is more common, but I have encountered the form *architect John Smith* enough times that it doesn't set off my "weird grammar" radar. I mainly consume American English if that is a factor.

Comment: Concerning bands, I believe I read it somewhere on Wikipedia, so it's neither a headline, nor a mistake, since these guys, I reckon, look after the grammar quite fervently. But without proof my statement here sounds unconvincing, I'll write back as soon as I find the article.

Comment: @Rusty I once spent an hour correcting some Wikipedia contributor's extremely dubious grammar only to find the original back in place the following day. Don't bank on universally high Wikipedian grammar standards.

Comment: I've just found this extract on Wikipedia, though there's no "by", but a "from"; but then again, it's a similar structure. So, according to you, this one is ungrammatical too?   *...These exceptions defied linguists for a few decades, but eventually received explanation from Danish linguist Karl Verner in the form of Verner's law.*

Comment: @RonaldSole So, this extract from Wikipedia is ungrammatical too? *The Iceberg Theory (sometimes known as the "theory of omission") is a style of writing (turned colloquialism) coined by American writer Ernest Hemingway.*